# Swift SKPhysicsBody falling through static SKPhysicsBody with matching bitmasks

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I am making a platforming game in Swift with SpriteKit involving a main character that jumps around. However, once the level loads the player immediately falls through the ground. [You can see it in action here.](https://youtu.be/BJZlKV9tNQ8)

I am using SKTilemapNode to create the ground, and looping through the tiles when a level loads to create an SKPhysicsBody on a child node of the tile map. This is very similar to what is demoed in the "What's new in SpriteKit" video at WWDC 2016:

> So, here we've got a little platform that I built. A little guy that can run around. And you can see that I got the parallax scrolling going on in the background. And you'll note that I'm colliding with the tiles here. And I achieve this by leveraging custom user data that we can put on each of our tiles. Here, I'll show you in our tile set. Select one of the variants here.
>   And you can see that we have some user data over here. And I just have a value called edgeTile which is a Boolean, and I set to 1.
>   So, in code, I'm going through the tile map in our platform demo here, and I'm looking for all of these edge tiles.
>   And whenever I find one, I create some physics data to allow the player to collide with it.

My function to create a physics body based off of an SKTilemapNode is as follows:

```
extension SKTileMapNode {

//In order for this to work, edge tile definitions must have the "edge" property in user data
func createPhysicsBody() -> SKPhysicsBody {
    var physicsBodies = [SKPhysicsBody]()

    for row in 0 ..< self.numberOfRows {
        for column in 0 ..< self.numberOfColumns {
            if self.tileDefinition(atColumn: column, row: row)?.userData?["edge"] != nil {
                physicsBodies.append(SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf: self.tileSize, center: self.centerOfTile(atColumn: column, row: row)))
            }

        }
    }

    let body = SKPhysicsBody(bodies: physicsBodies)
    body.affectedByGravity = false
    body.isDynamic = false
    body.allowsRotation = false
    body.pinned = true
    body.restitution = 0
    body.collisionBitMask = 0b1111
    body.categoryBitMask = 0b1111
    body.contactTestBitMask = 0b1000

    return body
}

func initializePhysicsBody() {
    let node = SKNode()
    node.name = "Tilemap"
    node.physicsBody = createPhysicsBody()

    addChild(node)
}

}
```

So, in my scene setup all I have to do is call `tileMap.initializePhysicsBody()` to do everything that I need.

The SKPhysicsBody for my player is as follows:

```
let rect = CGSize(width: 16 * xScale, height: 24 * yScale)
let physics = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf: rect)
physics.isDynamic = true
physics.allowsRotation = false
physics.pinned = false
physics.affectedByGravity = true
physics.friction = 0
physics.restitution = 0
physics.linearDamping = 0
physics.angularDamping = 0
physics.density = 100
physics.categoryBitMask = 0b0001
physics.collisionBitMask = 0b0001
physics.contactTestBitMask = 0b0011
physics.usesPreciseCollisionDetection = true

physicsBody = physics
```

I'm not sure what the problem is here, but if I set the SKTilemapNode's physics body to be dynamic, it works. This is how I had the game working up until this point, however, this creates a lot of jitter in the ground because it's moving as a result of the player hitting it. So, thanks for reading this far at least, and any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried switching body.isDynamic to true?

Comment: As I see, the player has intersect with the tiles on the first frame, in that case there isn't any collision. Could you please try to move the player above the tiles? Maybe it would work.

Comment: @PéterKovács thanks for your answer, but unfortunately my character still fell through @sicvayne yes, and this worked in the past for me, I just didn't think it made any sense for it to stop working once `body.isDynamic = false`. I ended up setting `body.isDynamic = false; body.mass = CGFloat(Int.max)` to work around this issue though.

Comment: Whoops, sorry everyone I meant `body.isDynamic = true; body.mass = CGFloat(Int.max)` to get it to work

Answer (score 0):

EDIT. 
I think the ERROR Here is not using UInt 32

```
body.categoryBitMask: UInt32 = 2
body.collisionBitMask: UInt32 = 1
body.contactTestBitMask: UInt32 = 1
```

And Player

```
physics.categoryBitMask: UInt32 = 1
physics.collisionBitMask: UInt32 = 2
physics.contactTestBitMask: UInt32 = 2
```

This should definitely Work

Also try this way for the tileMapNode (given below) rather than creating the extension. This was given in a apple developer forum by dontangg

```
self.tileMap = self.childNode(withName: "Tile Map") as? SKTileMapNode  
guard let tileMap = self.tileMap else { fatalError("Missing tile map for the level") }  

let tileSize = tileMap.tileSize  
let halfWidth = CGFloat(tileMap.numberOfColumns) / 2.0 * tileSize.width  
let halfHeight = CGFloat(tileMap.numberOfRows) / 2.0 * tileSize.height  

for col in 0..<tileMap.numberOfColumns {  
    for row in 0..<tileMap.numberOfRows {  
        let tileDefinition = tileMap.tileDefinition(atColumn: col, row: row)  
        let isEdgeTile = tileDefinition?.userData?["edgeTile"] as? Bool  
        if (isEdgeTile ?? false) {  
            let x = CGFloat(col) * tileSize.width - halfWidth  
            let y = CGFloat(row) * tileSize.height - halfHeight  
            let rect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: tileSize.width, height: tileSize.height)  
            let tileNode = SKShapeNode(rect: rect)  
            tileNode.position = CGPoint(x: x, y: y)  
            tileNode.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody.init(rectangleOf: tileSize, center: CGPoint(x: tileSize.width / 2.0, y: tileSize.height / 2.0))  
            tileNode.physicsBody?.isDynamic = false  
            tileNode.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = playerCollisionMask | wallCollisionMask  
            tileNode.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = wallCollisionMask  
            tileMap.addChild(tileNode)  
        }  
    }  
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I tried this but it didn't work unfortunately. I tried using an enum instead as well without any luck. Since I can't find any logical reason behind this, I decided to just set the tile map's physics body to be dynamic, and set it's mass to `CGFloat(Int.max)` which works well enough for me.

Comment: I have a working physics contact system. Using enum with : UInt32. Let me edit my Answer

Comment: Pls look at my edit. Remember to Use UInt32. It's important. Plus mine was not dynamic but it worked. This should definitely work. If you want more bitmasks it would go 4 8 16 32 etc.

Comment: This does not compile for me, I get an "Expected Expression" error at the colon on each line. Even formatting it as `body.categoryBitMask = UInt32(2)` for each line still does not work for me. Could just be something on my end, who knows.

Comment: I did some research and I think the problem here lies coz ur creating and extension of TileMapNode. I watched a bit of the video as well (it seems they use a bool to detect edge. I think the solution is mentioned in a forum here https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/50043  . I also copied the code above in the answer for easier reference. Goodluck :)